# how to find what specific line calls a website in js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I have a webpage in which there is some background call to some website which I can see using disconnect plugin in chrome, now I want to find which specific line calls the website in the background, how can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will works to this case, but in JS exists `debugger` sentence that can be called from any line. If you use it, the execution of the program will end at that line and show it to you

Comment: In the network tab of chrome dev tools there's an `Initiator` column. If you don't have it then right clicking will allow you to add it